# Exporting from gridview to excel is not showing long numbers

Tags: excel, gridview, export

Hello I'm trying to export my data from a gridview to excel the problem is I have a nvarchar column the have the following barcode: **00373228210001695726** and in excel after export it looks like this **3,73228E+17**

my query looks like this:

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AP;Initial Catalog=MGW;User Id=sa;Password=GaUbdFO2;App=EntityFramework;");
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sqlStatement = " ";
                sqlStatement += " SELECT UserName AS UserID, Site, AddressID, Parameters, Content AS Barcode , TriggerDate, ReceivedDate, Action, DeviceID, Longitude, Latitude, CASE WHEN Latitude != '' THEN 'View Map Location' Else 'No Location' END AS LatitudeMSG FROM RequestWithLocation WHERE";
                sqlStatement += " Content = @Content ";
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxStart.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxEnd.Text))
                {
                    sqlStatement += " AND TriggerDate >= @TriggerDateStart AND TriggerDate <= @TriggerDateEnd ";
                }
                sqlStatement += " ORDER BY TriggerDate DESC";
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", TextBoxSearch.Text);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxStart.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxEnd.Text))
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TriggerDateStart", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxStart.Text));
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TriggerDateEnd", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxEnd.Text).AddDays(+1));
                    }
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                    {
                        sqlDa.Fill(dt);

                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            GridDisplayData.DataSource = dt;
                            GridDisplayData.DataBind();
                            lblError.Text = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('No data found');", true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Search timed-out! try again..');", true);
            }
```

**EXPORT FUNCTION**

```
   protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachchment; filename=Report_EventScan.xls; IMEX=1;");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridDisplayData.RenderControl(hw);

        //Panel7.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to see the leading zeros?

Comment: yes I want my excel to show 00373228210001695726 as it is in the gridview and not 3,73228E+17 as it's showen in excel after that data has been exported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. this is what I did:
You can download the EPPlus Excel reader from here http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Then using OfficeOpenXml; on top of your project and the following code to your export button, this should work for everyone who use a **DataSet** which is saved in a **ViewState**

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     DataSet dt = new DataSet();
     dt = (DataSet)ViewState["QueryTable"];
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     int i = 1;
     using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
      {
       foreach (DataTable table in dt.Tables)
      {
       ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Excel Report " + i++);
       worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
            }
       Response.Clear();
       package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachchment; filename= test.xls");
       Response.Charset = "";
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
       Response.End();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Response.Write("'" + sw.ToString());` to force a prefixed single quotation character in front of the number. That forces Excel to adopt text formatting.

(I'm assuming that `+` is a string concatenation in your language; it might be `&`).

Comment: Im using aspx. I changed my export method in the end to Response.Write("'" + sw.ToString()); I still see no changed and it keeps showing 3,73228E+17

Comment: Could you please confirm that Response.Write actually writes the text to the Excel cell?

Comment: Alright I just made a string test. And then test = sw.toString();
My text value looks like this, I don't know if this is what you wanted to check: 
http://prntscr.com/2vqe24